# Is 1% m/m the same as 1% w/w?

Tags: concentration, units, pharmacology

Hydrocortisone cream seems to be sold as 1% w/w, but my cream is 1% m/m, which is confusing. Are they the same units or the same concentrations?

Answer (score 4):

“[M]ass is the amount of "matter" in an object (though "matter" may be difficult to define), whereas weight is the force exerted on an object by gravity.” ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_versus_weight) quoting [de Silva, G.M.S. (2002), *Basic Metrology for ISO 9000 Certification*, Butterworth-Heinemann, 214p.]

Well-known relationship:

$$
W = m \times g
$$

where *W* is weight, *m* is mass and *g* is the acceleration of gravity.

Because *g* is a constant that cancels out in a ratio, mass/mass and weight/weight are identical.

Likewise, the ratios % *m*/*m* and % *W*/*W* are identical.

Comment: Indeed m/m would be more appropriate. Thumb up for the pharmacists.

Comment: Let's be thankful the % units were labeled at all!

Answer (score 1):

The symbol “w/w” is more often used in chemistry, whereas its equivalent “m/m” is favored in pharmaceutical industry.
For instance, [European Pharmacopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Pharmacopoeia) in section *1.2. Other provisions applying to general
chapters and monographs* suggests the following methods for expressing concentration [1, pp. 4–5]:

> **Expression of content**. In defining content, the expression ‘per cent’ is used according to circumstances with one of 2 meanings:
>
> – per cent *m/m* (percentage, mass in mass) expresses the number of grams of substance in 100 g of ﬁnal product;
> – per cent *V/V* (percentage, volume in volume) expresses the number of millilitres of substance in 100 mL of final product.
>
> The expression ‘parts per million’ (or ppm) refers to mass in mass, unless otherwise specified.

Please note, however, that this is a somewhat flawed definition: neither of physical quantities such as “mass” or “volume” should be called or referred to as to “number
of grams” or “number of millilitres”, respectively.
Also, neither “w/w”, “V/V” nor “m/m” — despite their widespread usage — are considered correct by the [BIPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bureau_of_Weights_and_Measures) [2, p. 149]:

> #### 5.4.2 Quantity symbols and unit symbols
>
> Unit symbols must not be used to provide specific information about the quantity and should never be the sole source of information on the quantity.
> Units are never qualified by further information about the nature of the quantity; any extra information on the nature of the quantity should be attached to the quantity symbol and not to the unit symbol.
>
> For example:
>
> The maximum electric potential difference is $U_\mathrm{max} = \pu{1000 V}$ but not $U = \pu{1000 V_\mathrm{max}}.$
> The mass fraction of copper in the sample of silicon is $w(\ce{Cu}) = \pu{1.3E−6}$
> but not $\pu{1.3E−6 w/w}.$

Considering the aforementioned guidelines, the hydrocortisone (HCT) content should ideally be depicted as $w(\text{HCT}) = 1\,\%$ to avoid ambiguity.

#### References

1. Council of Europe; European Directorate for the Quality of Medicines & Healthcare. *European Pharmacopoeia*, 10th ed.; Council of Europe: Strasbourg, **2019**. ISBN 978-92-871-8912-7.
2. BIPM. *Le Système International d’unitès / The International System of Units (“The SI Brochure”)*, 9th ed.; Bureau international des poids et mesures: Sèvres, **2019**. ([PDF](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf#page=35))